# Send custom PostgreSQL queries result to DataDog

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, datadog

I am new to DataDog. We are planning to utilize it as a reporting tool. Below is the scenario:

1. Create a log table in Amazon RDS
2. Fetch some rows from the log table and send them to DataDOG.

I have read some documentation and found two ways to send data to DataDog. Below are the links:

1. https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/collect-postgresql-data-with-datadog/#collecting-custom-postgresql-metrics-with-datadog
2. https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/?tab=serverless

Is there any other way to send query results to Data Dog or directly query Aurora PostgreSQL(AWS)?
Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to send text data to DD logs? Any process that's monitored by the DD agent can query the DB and write the results to stdout. I would say this unlikely to be a common use case and I would reconsider your design. Why write the logs to the database first?

Comment: @jordanm: we are logging some api responses in our log table. The log table is not related to PostgreSQL metrics. We want to get the result of a simple query into DD and visualize the data.

Comment: You can also write that information to your application logs and have the DD agent forward your logs to DD. The intermediate step of putting into and pulling out the database seems unnecessary.

Comment: @jordanm: We are in the phase of finalizing the tool for monitoring purposes. Just wanted to check that do we have any easy way to pull the rows from user tables and push them to datadog.